# Pull specific value from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to pull the price from the following JSON but can't seem to figure out how to reference the actual values:

```
{"cards": [ { "high": "0.73", "volume": 1, "percent_change": "-2.67", "name": "Lightning Bolt", "url": "http://blacklotusproject.com/cards/Revised+Edition/Lightning+Bolt/", "price": "0.73", "set_code": "3ED", "average": "0.73", "change": "-0.02", "low": "0.73"}], "currency": "USD" }
```

So far I've got this code, which gets into the cards array but I'm unsure how to get farther - every attempt I've tried returns null.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url); $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo var_dump($data[cards]);
```

Can someone shed light on what I need to do?

Comment: no need to echo var_dump, and need to use quotes around keys.  $data['cards']   ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data['cards']` has another array within it. You will need to access this array with index `0`. For instance, `$data['cards'][0]['high']` and so on.

Comment: And instantly I see my problem - I was nesting the indexes rather than having them sequentially. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$data['cards']` is an array itself, so you could do:

```
foreach ($data['cards'] AS $carditem) {
    echo $carditem['high'];
    ...
}
```

to get all items in that array,
or if you only want the first item `$data['cards'][0]['...']`

Answer (score 0):

To access using a string literal array index, always use quotes.

```
$data["cards"]
```

Link: [PHP Documentation for Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)